# How do I find tension just as a particle has been released?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, classical-mechanics

[image]

I have two questions with this similar situation, and I genuinely have no clue where to start. I've already modelled the particles but I feel like I'm missing some information on how to find the tension in this scenario.

Comment: It's a two part question, the first part is the dynamics of the two particle system, the second is free fall of B as it no longer is attached to A

Comment: @Triatticus I've tried finding T when a=0, but I get the wrong answer. I also tried in a round about way via substituting and adding some equations and still ended up with nothing. Am I missing something?

Comment: You write down both equations, one for each particle, you should have two equations in the two variables a (acceleration) and T (tension), this value of a and T is the same for both particles. Best way to solve is to first find one variable through substitution and then find the second using one of the equations. Remember it's an application of Newton's second law for both

Comment: For instance newton's second law for both particles is $$F_{net \; A} = T = m_A a$$ $$F_{net \; B} = T - m_B g = -m_B a$$ where the negative sign indicates direction (in this case downward)